# How to see heap and stack usage of a function in c using valgrind?

Tags: c, embedded, arm, valgrind, memcheck

I  am working on a embedded system. We have limited stack and heap in our embedded system typically 64k (ram). I am trying to use polar-ssl library calls. Is there any  tools which tells how much stack and heap memory is used by a C function?

Is there any option is  in valgrind which prints the following:

1. Stack and heap usage of a function.
2. Call trace of functions which  calls internally malloc with no of bytes.

Comment: why dont u read Valgrind's document?

Comment: massif gives heap analysis (quite a lot of it, but usable).

Answer (score 5):

There is a valgrind tool massif that measures how much heap memory an application uses. Similarly memcheck can give you stack trace. More explanation here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Linux_Tools_Project/Valgrind/User_Guide#Analyzing_Memcheck_Profile_Results